# Notice: Array to string conversion - Why?

Tags: php, reference, notice

Hi im trying to execute the following PHP code, however im receiving an error. Im passing a reference into the core class, which i want to assign to a variable within the classes scope..

Notice: Array to string conversion

Thanks in advance..

```
$core = new core($config);
$core->execute();
```

```
class core
{
   private $config;

   public function __construct(&$config)
   {
      $this->$config = $config;
   }

   public function execute()
   {
      $this->set_path();
   }

   private function set_path()
   {
      return true;      
   }  
}
```

Comment: an exact copy of error message would be highly valuable

Comment: What is the error you speak of :)

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in core.class.php on line 9   

That's all there is... Im not sure why its generating the notice.. Im not trying to convert the array to a string.. I just want to pass the reference into the class scope.

Comment: This line: $this->$config = $config;
Should be $this->config = $config;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, first off....

```
$this->$config
```

The second `$` in `$config` should be removed since otherwise it's trying to access the variable with the name given by the string within `$config`. (e.g., if $config held `"test"` as a value, you'd be accessing the `"test"` variable within your class: `$this->test`)

What is `$config` when it is passed in, anyway?  (String, array, object, etc?)

Comment: Ahh.. dummy mistake.. I've been looking at that for a little aswell.. Sorry to waste your time..

$config is an array.

Answer (score 1):

private $config = array();

Comment: I thought because it is a reference it wouldnt need declaring as an array?

Comment: Tried the solution, it didnt work. The same error message was generated.

Comment: well you don't *need* to...according to OP it's a "notice"

Answer (score 1):

`$this->config = $config;`

Answer (score 0):

This works without errors in php 5.2.
What version of php are you using?

```
<?php
class core
{
   private $config;

   public function __construct(&$config)
   {
      $this->config = $config;
   }

   public function execute()
   {
      $this->set_path();
   }

   private function set_path()
   {
      return true;      
   }  
}

$config=array(
     'a'    => '1'
    ,'b'    => '2'
    );

$core = new core($config);
$core->execute();
```